# error en module loaders de webpack

Tags: webpack

me encuentro con el siguiente freno,

Estoy agregando unos loaders a mi webpack.config.js
El código es el siguiente:

```
module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './test.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: __dirname
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
                    {
                        test: /(\.js|.jsx)$/,
                        loader: 'babel',
                        query: {
                          presets: ['es2015', 'stage-2', 'react']
                        }
                    }
        ]
    }
};
```

Y al ejecutar el watch del webpack

```
webpack --watch
```

Veo el siguiente error por consola:

> Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a
>   configuration object that does not match the API schema.
>    - configuration.module has an unknown property 'loaders'. These properties are valid:    object { exprContextCritical?,
>   exprContextRecursive?, exprContextRegExp?, exprContextRequest?,
>   noParse?, rules?, defaultRules?, unknownContextCritical?,
>   unknownContextRecursive?, unknownContextRegExp?,
>   unknownContextRequest?, unsafeCache?, wrappedContextCritical?,
>   wrappedContextRecursive?, wrappedContextRegExp?,
>   strictExportPresence?, strictThisContextOnImports? }    -> Options
>   affecting the normal modules (`NormalModuleFactory`).

Cabe destacar que si elimino los loaders no veo ningun error

Comment: No veo nada similar en la [documentación de webpack](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/#options), parece que esa opción [está descontinuada](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#rule-loaders)

Comment: gracias, voy a probar con otras entonces

Comment: la verdad me pasa con cualquier configuracion, por ejemplo con la siguiente: 


 loaders: [
    { test: /\.scss$/, loader: 'style!css!sass', exclude: /node_modules/ }
   ]

Answer (score 1):

Parece que tu configuración debería ser algo como:

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './test.js',
    output: {
      filename: 'bundle.js',
      path: __dirname
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /(\.js|.jsx)$/,
          use: {
            loader:'babel',
            options: {
              presets: ['es2015', 'stage-2', 'react']
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
};
```

Comment: gracias pero al parecer el probelma era de compatibilidad entre node, webpack y quien sabe si algo mas, desinstale todo, volvi a instalar node pero una version anterior y webpack 4.0 y me funcionaron los loaders, al parecer algo estaba en conflicto